# Google script - Document - How to delete the first line added to the new document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am struggling to avoid having a first line when creating a new document with google script.

You can see if you execute the short example below in the script.google.com script editor that there is a line above my easy table.

Could you help me to figure out how to delete this empty line? And that my table becomes the first element after the top margin of my document?

Many thanks

```
function displayStepData() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Test document');
  doc.getBody().clear();


  // Get the body object
  var body = doc.getBody();
  // Set the size of the body on the page
  body.setPageWidth(842);
  body.setPageHeight(595);
  body.setMarginLeft(41.5);
  body.setMarginRight(41.5);
  body.setMarginTop(40);
  body.setMarginBottom(41.5);

  var text_header =  [['company help center: ','','My logo to add']];
  var table_header = body.insertTable(0,text_header);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove this

[image]

Unfortunately you can't. Each tables in google documents has a previous paragraph.

If you is adding an image into a cell then you can remove the external line

```
function myFunction() {
    var image = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://source.unsplash.com/pFqrYbhIAXs/400x300').getBlob();
    var table = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getTables()[0];
    var cell = table.getRow(0).getCell(0);
    cell.insertImage(0, image);
    if (cell.getNumChildren() > 1) cell.removeChild(cell.getChild(1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The thing is that when I add a picture inside a table cell with google script, it adds also this line on the top of the cell before the picture but I can delete it manually on the document. I guess there must be a way to delete this line from the google script document, no?

Comment: @fabro5, this is not the same thing. Look at the example.